# How to count values in string seperated by delimeter in excel using formula only?

Tags: excel

I am trying to count the names in following string:

John/Bill/Robert/Edward

I need to know inbuild formula to count the names. as per above example I should get 4 as result.

Comment: What is the string element defining the number of names? And what happens if you delete this element from the string?

Comment: it is manual entry. and it does not have deletion. i type it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps count the slashes and add 1 - catering for blanks that would be this formula for a single cell

`=IF(A1="",0,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))+1)`

If you want to count across a range use this version

`=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10<>"")+0,LEN(A1:A10)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A10,"/",""))+1)`